# IBM Notes - a REST API or Webservice or a simple agent that returns info about Out of Office

Tags: web-services, lotusscript, lotus-notes

Does any one know of any webservice/api/simple agent (that can run with in Domino enviroment) that can say a person is out of office currently based on their mail box settings. I mean not based on any internal leave management systems.

Thanks in advance.
Kalyan

Comment: Came across session.sendConsoleCommand(server, command) in lotusscript but am unable to capture the result as it says "Command has been executed on remote server. Use 'Live' console option, in future, to view response from server.". I have FullAdmin rights to access remote console and send commands. Tried to re-direct output to a file as well, but with no luck. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is very close to what you are looking for :

http://www.openntf.org/projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/0/BB507CA70A768C808625706800033E86

It appears that it wouldn't take much work to adapt it you suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Server command  "tell router o" would get us a list of users who are out of office. I want to capture the return value since that is not happening via lotusscript variable nor by re-directing the output to a  file. I always get the error message I pasted on my previous comment.